# How to import big sql file in Phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am having a big sql file( 16mb) and all i need is to upload it to the Phpmyadmin to work with it in my localhost. I'm a newbie here in Php/MySql and i want to know about the details regarding the work.So, please suggest me the best.

Cheers and waiting for response.

Comment: Would suite on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maximum file size you can upload is specified in your php.ini [ the configuration file for php ]. You would like to look for `upload_max_filesize = 2M` and change it to something else, for example 20M. You can also try to compress your file size, phpadmin accepts many different archives, like zip, gz etc.

Comment: many thanks for ur response. As i mentioned i'm a newbie so not so many knowledge in Php but Java :) ok, i'm going through it and getting back to you.

Comment: @mkk - i can't find any php.ini file there..what i hav is the only database and the tables..so now what to do next?

Comment: @RajdeepRoy you might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line#answer-2750582) useful - it should help you localize php.ini . If it will not help you, please come back to me. It will be useful to know what OS you are using

Comment: @mkk- what i have is one folder with DB tables, another one with some php pages and finally the sql file (which is 16mb)..and nothing else..now please tell me how to get that sql file run in my localhost...i m using win-7 as my OS..new in Php :P..thatz the best i can say :)--- Awaiting response deeply

Comment: @RajdeepRoy do you really need to use phpmyadmin after that? Can't you just write in the comand line `mysql -u  *username-probably_root* -p *your_database_name* < *sql_file*` ? If you do not have password you do not need to use `-p` option. That will be simpler approach :)

Comment: If you need to use phpymadmin we need to localize php.ini or create one [ default setting might b applied ]. I believe there should be `config` directory, which should include php.ini ? You also had to manually installed php5, for example in C:/php5 - php.ini should be there.

Comment: do u mean in the command prompt? i have never used that way. Still a bit confused. Shall i write  -u*username-probably_root*....and everything ? mixing it up err

Comment: text between * is depending on your settings, most likely you use default settings, and the default username is root. Let's assume that you do not have password for mysql, and your database's name is my_database. If your sql file name is 'file.sql', then the proper command is `mysql -u root my_database < file.sql`. You must be inside directory, in which the file exists, if it is on your desktop for example and your username is Roy, then before this command you should type `cd C:/Users/Roy/Desktop` [cd = change directory]